# Add color to rectangle

Tags: objective-c, c, ipad, quartz-graphics

I want to make a circle with a fill color. This is my code:

```
    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 34, 102, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 135, 206, 250, 0.5);
    rectangle = CGRectMake(1, 1, 500, 500);
    CGContextAddArc(context, pointWhereUserClickedX, pointWhereUserClickedY, 50, 0, 2*3.14159265359, YES);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

When I run it, the fill color is white, even though I have filled with a blue color. I have the same problem when I want to add a background rectangle behind two "towers" rectangles:

```
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//Background styling
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 202, 255, 112, 1);

//Background setup
background = CGRectMake(1, 1, 1024, 786);               
CGContextAddRect(context, background);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

//Styling
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 225, 1);

//first tower setup
firstTower = CGRectMake(20, 20, 25, 100);
CGContextAddRect(context, firstTower);

//second tower setup
secondTower = CGRectMake(20, 800, 25, 100);
CGContextAddRect(context, secondTower);

//Draw towers
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

When I add the background color, I still can't see any change. It's just white, so I guess it's the same problem as the circle. The second tower isn't displayed at all either.

What is wrong? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Read the docs for `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` and see what the parameter values are supposed to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz commands require colour parameters to be in the range of 0 and 1 (float). This line here (an the others similar with it):

`CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 135, 206, 250, 0.5);`

should actually be:

`CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 135.0/255.0, 206.0/255.0, 250.0/255.0, 0.5);`